# Does OCaml have a popcnt function?

Tags: ocaml, bit-manipulation, instructions

Can the `popcnt`, `bsf`, `bsr` and `lzcnt` instructions be generated in native OCaml on x86 CPUs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have OCaml 4.01.0 sources handy, and for this it's pretty easy to check. If you look for these instructions in the code generation sources, they do not appear.

```
$ pwd
/home/jeffsco/oc41/asmcomp/i386
$ ls
arch.ml       emit_nt.mlp   reload.ml     selection.ml
emit.mlp      proc.ml       scheduling.ml
$ grep -w popcnt *
$ grep -w bsf *
$ grep -w bsr *
$ grep -w lzcnt *
```

If I look for something like `movl` I get plenty of hits:

```
$ grep -w movl *
emit.mlp:              `    movl    {emit_reg src}, {emit_reg dst}\n`
emit.mlp:          | _     -> ` movl    $0, {emit_reg i.res.(0)}\n`
. . .
```

So, I strongly suspect the answer is no. Perhaps things have changed for OCaml 4.02, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a binding to the hardware instruction in Jane Street's base library:

Cf. https://github.com/janestreet/base/blob/master/src/popcount.ml

In the interface:

```
val int_popcount       : int       -> int
val int32_popcount     : int32     -> int
val int64_popcount     : int64     -> int
val nativeint_popcount : nativeint -> int`
```

int_popcount is the one you are looking for.

Cf. this C file for the details (where you can see that they
use __builtin_popcount):

https://github.com/janestreet/base/blob/master/src/int_math_stubs.c

There is also a popcount in the zarith library, which used
the GMP implementation.

```
Z.popcount
```

PS: thanks to Francois Bobot for telling me about the one in zarith